# Josephus Problem with every third person

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the Josephus problem when every third person is killed. I've read the explanation of the generalized Josephus problem in the Wikipedia article (and every second problem explanation from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE)), but I do not really understand the general solution. For example, it states the following:

> Let `f(n,k)` denote the position of the survivor. After the k-th
>   person is killed, we're left with a circle of n-1, and we start the
>   next count with the person whose number in the original problem was `(k mod n) + 1` .

But lets say, if I take the example of n=5 and k=3, then in the first round when the 3rd person is killed, in the next `n-1` sized circle, the killing would start from 4 and not `(3 mod 5) + 1 = 3` as the above line states. Could anyone please help me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: What is `(3 mod 5) + 1`?  Is it $3$ or is it $4$?  Perhaps it would be clearer for them to have written $(k+1)\pmod{n}$, but that seems to be what is intended.

Comment: Its `(k mod n) + 1`, which is 3 for `k=3`, and `n = 5`. So, yep, 3 and not 4. I still don't kinda understand it. Aren't you changing the definition completely? I mean its `k` and not `k+1` whose mod we take with respect to n. Is the Wikipedia definition not correct?

Comment: The wikipedia article itself writes it as `(k mod n) + 1` not as `k mod (n+1)`, these are two different things.  First apply `k mod n` and then to the result of that add one.  `3 mod 5` is 3, and then adding one to the result makes it now `4` so no, it is in fact 4 and not 3.  They likely wrote it this way in order to avoid the possibility of a result of zero.  Here, they are using mod as an operator (*as opposed to a contextual setting like mathematicians usually do*).

Comment: Worded a different, less confusing way, when a person is killed, for the next round begin counting from the person who sat to the left of the newly deceased.  All of the talk using modular operations is just in order to have a way to write down the person's number in a precise fashion so that we can avoid the possibility of accidentally calling a person a number which is too large or too small to be possible.

Comment: Ohh, right, now I get it! Thanks a lot for putting it in a much more simplified way :) That really cleared it up.